# Insert Unicode / charset Data into SQL Server 2012 using VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, unicode

I need help again. I am using SqlBulkCopy to insert xls file into sql server 2012. 
The problem is, when I insert the data that contains Chinese character or 'Â' symbol or '&' symbol it will change into another character. 
I have added:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html";charset="utf-8">
```

into my code page, but still not working

Comment: please post your code; to get any help with your code you must share it...

Comment: sql server handles unicode data with nchar, nvarchar data types. make sure you are not using char or varchar instead.

Comment: Hi Zohar Thanks! I have changed the dataType into nvarchar and it's working.

Comment: Hi Zohar, I want to ask again. The Chinese character is return correctly but why the '&' symbol change into '&amp;' ? How can I fix this?

Comment: This is not the result of using sql server. you probably call HTMLEncode somewhere in your code. to decode it back, use [`HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx) Method.

Comment: Hi Thanks again. Problem solved :) . `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(txtname)`

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept my answer so that other people will know that the problem is solved directly from the question's list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql server handles unicode data with `nchar` and `nvarchar` data types. make sure you are not using `char` or `varchar` instead.

As for your next question in the comments, Sql server does not change `&` to `&amp;`. This is probably the result of using `HttpServerUtility`'s [`HtmlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx) method somewhere in your code. To replace back to `&`, all you have to do is use `HttpServerUtility`'s [`HtmlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx) method.